# date format sqlite 3

Tags: sqlite, date

I created a table with different columns: the 1st one contains the id_column and the 2nd contains date_camp. 
The format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD. 
I tried to extract the id_column corresponding of the 2014-01-01 but i don't get it.

I wrote different queries:

```
SELECT id_column FROM TABLE
WHERE date_camp='2014-01-01'

SELECT id_colum FROM TABLE
WHERE date_camp=date('2014-01-01')
```

both queries return no id_column.

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: This would have worked if the format really was `yyyy-mm-dd`. What is the actual format of the values in this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will solve your problem.

```
SELECT id_column FROM TABLE
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date_camp)='2014-01-01'
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i used the function strftime and i got the good results

Comment: @Anais http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up mark as up vote or accept if you satisfied.